# OMSETRENDERTARGETS_INVALIDVIEW on switching RenderTargets (DirectX)

Tags: c++, directx, render, rendertarget

i was trying to render to a texture to use it for post-processing. I've read a lot of tutorials about this stuff und have tried it for myself now, but apparently i am doing something wrong. I already was asking another question regarding this topic, but since this question is a differnt one i think it is a better idea to create a new one.
So first of all these are the error message im getting over and over:

```
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets: The RenderTargetView at slot 0 is not compatable with the DepthStencilView. DepthStencilViews may only be used with RenderTargetViews if the effective dimensions of the Views are equal, as well as the Resource types, multisample count, and multisample quality. The RenderTargetView at slot 0 has (w:400,h:300,as:1), while the Resource is a Texture2D with (mc:1,mq:0). The DepthStencilView has (w:1280,h:720,as:1), while the Resource is a Texture2D with (mc:1,mq:0). D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE factors into the Resource type, unless GetFeatureLevel() returns D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1 or greater. [ STATE_SETTING ERROR #388: OMSETRENDERTARGETS_INVALIDVIEW ]
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: Rasterization Unit is enabled (PixelShader is not NULL or Depth/Stencil test is enabled and RasterizedStream is not D3D11_SO_NO_RASTERIZED_STREAM) but position is not provided by the last shader before the Rasterization Unit. [ EXECUTION ERROR #362: DEVICE_DRAW_POSITION_NOT_PRESENT ]
```

And:

```
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: Vertex Shader - Geometry Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. The input stage requires Semantic/Index (RADIUS,0) as input, but it is not provided by the output stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #342: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_SEMANTICNAME_NOT_FOUND ]
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: Vertex Shader - Geometry Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. The input stage requires Semantic/Index (TEXTUREINDEX,0) as input, but it is not provided by the output stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #342: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_SEMANTICNAME_NOT_FOUND ]
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::Draw: Geometry Shader - Pixel Shader linkage error: Signatures between stages are incompatible. The input stage requires Semantic/Index (POSITION,0) as input, but it is not provided by the output stage. [ EXECUTION ERROR #342: DEVICE_SHADER_LINKAGE_SEMANTICNAME_NOT_FOUND ]
D3D11: ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::OMSetRenderTargets: The RenderTargetView at slot 0 is not compatable with the DepthStencilView. DepthStencilViews may only be used with RenderTargetViews if the effective dimensions of the Views are equal, as well as the Resource types, multisample count, and multisample quality. The RenderTargetView at slot 0 has (w:400,h:300,as:1), while the Resource is a Texture2D with (mc:1,mq:0). The DepthStencilView has (w:1280,h:720,as:1), while the Resource is a Texture2D with (mc:1,mq:0). D3D11_RESOURCE_MISC_TEXTURECUBE factors into the Resource type, unless GetFeatureLevel() returns D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_10_1 or greater. [ STATE_SETTING ERROR #388: OMSETRENDERTARGETS_INVALIDVIEW ]
```

I am pretty sure that i am misunterstanding a major aspect of this rendertarget switching and stuff.
When my DirectX Device is created i am also creating this:

```
    D3D11_TEXTURE2D_DESC textureDesc;
    D3D11_RENDER_TARGET_VIEW_DESC renderTargetViewDesc;
    D3D11_SHADER_RESOURCE_VIEW_DESC shaderResourceViewDesc;

    ZeroMemory(&textureDesc, sizeof(textureDesc));

    textureDesc.Width = 800/2;
    textureDesc.Height = 600/2;
    textureDesc.MipLevels = 1;
    textureDesc.ArraySize = 1;
    textureDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32A32_FLOAT;
    textureDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
    textureDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    textureDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE;
    textureDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
    textureDesc.MiscFlags = 0;


    pDevice->CreateTexture2D(&textureDesc, NULL, &renderTargetTextureMap);

    renderTargetViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
    renderTargetViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_RTV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    renderTargetViewDesc.Texture2D.MipSlice = 0;

    .
    pDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(renderTargetTextureMap, &renderTargetViewDesc, &renderTargetViewMap);

    shaderResourceViewDesc.Format = textureDesc.Format;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.ViewDimension = D3D11_SRV_DIMENSION_TEXTURE2D;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MostDetailedMip = 0;
    shaderResourceViewDesc.Texture2D.MipLevels = 1;

    pDevice->CreateShaderResourceView(renderTargetTextureMap, &shaderResourceViewDesc, &shaderResourceViewMap);

    D3DVERTEX quad[4] = {
        {D3DXVECTOR3(0,0,0), D3DXVECTOR2(0,0)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(1,1,0), D3DXVECTOR2(1,1)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(1,0,0), D3DXVECTOR2(1,0)},
        {D3DXVECTOR3(0,1,0), D3DXVECTOR2(0,1)}};

    HRESULT hr;

    D3D11_SUBRESOURCE_DATA InitData;
    InitData.pSysMem = &quad[0];
    InitData.SysMemPitch = sizeof(D3DVERTEX);
    InitData.SysMemSlicePitch = 0;

    D3D11_BUFFER_DESC bufferDesc;
    bufferDesc.Usage            = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
    bufferDesc.ByteWidth        = 4 * InitData.SysMemPitch;
    bufferDesc.BindFlags        = D3D11_BIND_VERTEX_BUFFER;
    bufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags   = 0;
    bufferDesc.MiscFlags        = 0;

    V_RETURN(pDevice->CreateBuffer( &bufferDesc, &InitData, &m_pVertexBuffer ));

    const D3D11_INPUT_ELEMENT_DESC layout[] = // http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb205117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx
    {
        { "POSITION",          0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32B32_FLOAT, 0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
        { "TEXCOORD",          0, DXGI_FORMAT_R32G32_FLOAT,    0, D3D11_APPEND_ALIGNED_ELEMENT, D3D11_INPUT_PER_VERTEX_DATA, 0 },
    };
    UINT numElements = sizeof( layout ) / sizeof( layout[0] );
    D3DX11_PASS_DESC passDesc;
    m_pEffect->GetTechniqueByName("Render")->GetPassByName("P0_PP")->GetDesc(&passDesc);

    V_RETURN( pDevice->CreateInputLayout( layout, numElements, passDesc.pIAInputSignature,
              passDesc.IAInputSignatureSize, &m_pInputLayout ) );
```

So i am creating a ShaderResourceView and a RenderTargetView aswell as a cube with a vertex buffer to draw this cube where the texture will be drawn on.

Now in every frame update after ALL the other stuff was drawn im using this:

```
    pDevice->GetImmediateContext(&pd3dImmediateContext);
    pd3dImmediateContext->OMSetRenderTargets( 1, &renderTargetViewMap, pDSV );

    pd3dImmediateContext->ClearRenderTargetView(renderTargetViewMap, g_ClearColor);
    ID3D11Buffer* vbs[] = { m_pVertexBuffer, };
    unsigned int strides[] = { sizeof(D3DVERTEX), }, offsets[] = { 0, };

    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetVertexBuffers(0,1, vbs, strides, offsets);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetInputLayout(m_pInputLayout);
    pd3dImmediateContext->IASetPrimitiveTopology(D3D11_PRIMITIVE_TOPOLOGY_POINTLIST);

    //TODO: Move to header file.
    ID3DX11EffectShaderResourceVariable* g_SpriteEV;

    g_SpriteEV = m_pEffect->GetVariableByName("g_PostProcessTex")->AsShaderResource();

    g_SpriteEV->SetResource(shaderResourceViewMap);
    m_pEffect->GetTechniqueByName("Render")->GetPassByName("P0_PP")->Apply(0, pd3dImmediateContext);

    pd3dImmediateContext->Draw(4, 0);
```

I have not explicitly created a depthStencilView which i would guess is my main error here. But i have no idea how to create something like this right.
I am pretty much confused about how this all is working in the background...maybe someone cares to explain this.
Am i doing anything right here or is this just wrong? :p

Thanks for anyone who cares to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think i was able to do it with the help of this tutorial:
http://www.rastertek.com/dx11tut22.html